# Implementing SHA1withRSA in Java

Tags: java, c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to port a C++ program to Java, but not having much luck. The algorithm being used is `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5`. <s>I know Java behaves differently from many other languages when it comes to cryptographic stuff.</s>

This is known to be working:

```
bssl::UniquePtr<RSA> rsa(RSA_new());
rsa->n = BN_bin2bn(server_key, sizeof(server_key), nullptr);
rsa->e = BN_new();
BN_set_word(rsa->e, 65537);

std::uint8_t gs_hash[20];
SHA1(gs.data(), gs.size(), gs_hash);

if (1 != RSA_verify(NID_sha1, gs_hash, sizeof(gs_hash), gs_sig.data(), gs_sig.size(), rsa.get())) {
  // failed
}
```

My current implementation:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

byte[] serverKey = new byte[] {...};

KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(serverKey), BigInteger.valueOf(65537)));

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
byte[] gs_hash = digest.digest(gs);

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA/PSS", "BC");
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(gs_hash);

if (sig.verify(gs_sig)) System.out.println("ALL GOOD");
else System.out.println("FAIL");
```

I've also tried using `SHA1withRSA` for the signature. `gs` and `gs_sig` are known and respectively 96 and 256 bytes long.

Test values:

```
serverKey: 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
gs: 4f2d7c6e76ccb6400ae1ff560d55a8084d98563ae03ac109d899fde735f6490935383cd1a97aa1fbff12e646f837194e9c6e57e1c5f956fcfde446a387c6be9a35c3225475f86df5a2c9b94626a2f90da3673af9861e33e8851a9a0ae20b9809
gs_signature: 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
gs_hash: 41aed19785bc5f4ffaa7eb30a29b1a39d52a225a
```

Comment: I don't know what "SHA1withRSA/PSS" is. I also see no reason to explicitly specify the BC provider in the `.getInstance()` method.  The Signature class includes the hashing functionality, that is why you specify a hash algorithm in the `.getInstance()`. You just feed the message to be verified directly into the `.update()` or `.verifiy()` . method. By passing a hash you are causing the message to be hashed twice.

Comment: The PSS scheme is definitely not PKCS 1.5. It has been defined in PKCS#1 v2.0, which meant the other (at that time *only*) scheme be named PKCS#1 v1.5 afterwards. Instead of blaming Java for anything, you might want to update your knowledge. Java is definitely very standards compliant when it comes to crypto - the only thing that is slightly special is the provider / service structure of the JCA, but that's well defined as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong:

1. You don't need to hash yourself when using `"SHA1withRSA"` (the signature will do the hashing for you, just feed it the data) and
2. if you add `"/PSS"` then you're using a different scheme than PKCS#1 v1.5.

`BigInteger(byte[])` will create a negative value if used with the modulus. You need to use `BigInteger(1, byte[])` to make it a positive value. However, both Bouncy as the JCE should throw an exception on negative exponents, so I don't see how you make your code run anyway.

Comment: Still can't get it working. I've updated the question with some know working values.

Comment: Those working values simply work. You have still printed `gs_hash` out, so I don't think you've read my answer fully. Note that `new BigInteger(serverKey)` cannot work correctly and throws an exception when used during the key generation. So I think you're either not showing the full / correct code to replicate the issue.

Comment: I did not know about the BigInteger thing, that made it work. Thank you. P.S. I did read your answer fully before, and I printed `gs_hash` just because it appears in the C++ program. Also, the Java program runs perfectly without the last change, maybe you should update your Java knowledge too. There's no point in being rude :)

Comment: OK, but making remarks like " I know Java behaves differently from many other languages when it comes to cryptographic stuff." is so blatantly wrong that it is just asking for a flame war.

Comment: Just curious, you say that Java (well, in your case Bouncy Castle) runs fine without the last change. Did you maybe prefix your modulus with a `00` byte yourself? You've indicated that you're directly using a byte array instead of a hex encoded value after all.

Comment: Nope, I did not prefix anything with a zero byte. Also, it worked with BC the same way it does with JCA.